# I want to embed youtube video link in my website. how can i do this?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

Here is my code

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptVideo"><ItemTemplate>
 <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 nopadding">
     <h3><b><%#Eval("Title")%></b></h3>
   <iframe width="500" height="200" src='<%#Eval("Video")%>' frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></a>
  </div>
 </ItemTemplate>
```

Here is my c# code

```
public void getGallery()
{
    cmd.CommandText = "Getvideo_Home";
    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
    //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", Request.QueryString["id"]);
    DataTable dtb = dboMrk.GetDataTableFrmDB(cmd);
    if (dtb.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        rptVideo.DataSource = dtb;
        rptVideo.DataBind();
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
    }
}
```

Here is my stored procedure

```
create proc [dbo].[Getvideo_Home]

As 

select * from Video where Status='A' and Video is not null
order by Id desc
```

Comment: instead of `*` try to pick the Column name explicitly

Comment: What columns do you have in the table `Video`? What errors, if any, do you get with your code? Are rows returned from your query? What is the actual problem you have?